# Async JSON mapping with Jackson and Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, jackson, retrofit, android-livedata

We use a Repository in order to provide information to an activity through a ViewModel.

We use Retrofit 2 to perform network operations and Jackson for JSON mapping. Here how this is performed inside the repository:

```
private fun getRemoteSuggestions(locale: String, term: String, pos: String): LiveData<Suggestions?> {
    val suggestionLiveData: MutableLiveData<Suggestions?> = MutableLiveData()

    if (request != null) {
        request?.cancel()
    }

    request = autocompleteService.fetch(locale, term, pos)
    request?.enqueue {
        onResponse = { response ->
            val payload = response.body()?.payload
            payload?.let {
                val suggestions = objectMapper().treeToValue(payload, Suggestions::class.java)
                if (suggestions.isEmpty()) {
                    suggestions.error = ServiceError(Errors.NO_DATA_FOUND)
                }
                if (waitingForTerm == term) suggestionLiveData.postValue(suggestions)
            } ?: run {
                if (waitingForTerm == term) suggestionLiveData.postValue(null)
            }
        }
        onFailure = { error ->
            Logger.d("Need to throw exception")
        }
    }
    return suggestionLiveData
}
```

As far as we know `enqueue` performs network calls in a background thread, but `onResponse` works in the main thread.
Could adding Anko `doAsync{}` be a possible solution?

```
private fun getRemoteSuggestions(locale: String, term: String, pos: String): LiveData<Suggestions?> {
    ...
        onResponse = { response ->
            doAsync {
                ...
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

In addition this is how we update our RecycleView.

```
this.autocompleteViewModel.getSuggestions(term).observe(this, Observer {
    if (this.searchTriggered) return@Observer
    it?.let { suggestions ->
        val sections = autocompleteViewModel.getAutocompleteSections(term.length, suggestions)
        runOnUiThread {
            autocompleteAdapter?.add(sections)
        }
    }
})
```

What do you think? Are there any better solutions?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to guess what the cause of your perceived lag and poor performance. I recommend you to use the profiler built in to Android Studio to get a better unerstanding 
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler?

Comment: Thank you for your response. What about Retrofit, Jackson and LiveData? Do you think we use them in the right way?